# Selenium - How to get a local WebDriver by Browser name

Tags: selenium, webdriver

A RemoteWebDriver could be instantiated via browsername like "firefox" via DesiredCapabilties object.

But how to get a local driver like "FireFoxDriver" with browser name?

My use case is as follows: the browsers to be tested are specified via properties in an external text file. with another property the grid url is set. if grid url is set to "local" i want to run the tests local on the browsers set in text file.

(how) is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Something in the way of this?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = openBrowser(args[0]);
    // now work with driver as usual
}

public static WebDriver openBrowser(String browserName) {
    if ((browserName == null) || (browserName.trim().isEmpty())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No browser name found.");
    }

    // works with Java 7, on Java < 7, you have to write an if-else block instead
    switch (browserName.toLowerCase()) {
        case "ff": // fall through
        case "firefox":
            return new FirefoxDriver();
        case "ie": // fall through
        case "iexplore": // fall through
        case "internet explorer":
            return new InternetExplorerDriver();
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No valid browser name found.");
    }
}
```

Comment: that is what i don't want to do: change the code to support an additional browser. with a constructor that takes a string (like remote web driver does) it is enough to change an external text file to test an additional browser.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a hack. Launch selenium-server on your local machine and then you can use remotewebdriver with host url as `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`.

This way you would be able to use same remote driver and external text file to control your tests on the local machine.

Comment: thx for this advice - i'll think about that. at the moment the local test only runs on firefox.